# "You must award it to an answer within 24 hours" Not even one answer yet

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I received this in my Inbox:

> bounty expiring soon 3 mins ago Your bounty on question "[Domino game
>   maximum achievable points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091748/domino-game-maximum-achievable-points)" is completed. You must award it to an
>   answer within 24 hours.

I should not see the last sentence if I do not have yet any answer!

Comment: This is just a generic statement. There's no point in detecting whether or not an answer exists. However, in relation, I think closed questions shouldn't allow bounties. Too easy for a user to be browsing and inadvertently give a bounty that they can never award.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck:  Didn't you discover that you could not close a Question while it has a bounty?  In any case this particular Question is not closed.

Comment: A bounty guarantees attention. It doesn't guarantee an answer. This has been discussed here before. See questions with the "bounty" tag.

Comment: @hardmath No, I meant the other way around. A question shouldn't be valid for a bounty whilst closed. It was just a thought I had. Also, I cannot close posts.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you misunderstand. The user is saying that the text "You must award it to an answer within 24 hours." is telling them to do something they cannot and therefore that sentence shouldn't appear to them. It should just say the bounty is complete.

Comment: OK. If you see an instruction that doesn't apply to you, just ignore it.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck There is also no point in saying"You must award it to an answer within 24 hours.", and seems to me it is doable with 1 line of code `if` statement or something similar. Why do I have to read such pointless thing?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: My answer to your last comment is my previous one to TheGreatDuck

Comment: Clearly, the programmers behind SE do not always ensure consistency of their system. However, it does not seem to cause any serious problems, yet.

Comment: @sergiol html is incredibly complex at times. It's easier to make a generic statement than it is to query the database to see whether an answer is present. It's not the if statement that's the problem. It's the conditional of the if statement. idk, if you have learned any database programming, but it's sometimes far easier to avoid querying the database if at all possible.... especially for something so trivial to ignore.